# Azure B2C - Can't get a B2C user flow to work with another Azure AD instance as a custom identity provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-platform

I have set up a B2C instance OK and managed to get a basic Blazor (server) app working with it a using the Microsoft Identity Platform (using AD groups for permissions - it was a hassle but works).

However, I'm trying to use an external Azure AD as a custom identity provider in the user flow, so that I am not just restricted to just email/id/social accounts, but can have guest accounts from other directories use the app without having to manage their sign-in's. To do that I performed a web app registration in the AD tenant that I wanted to use to authenticate those accounts against (as suggested in a couple of tutorials).

The application I registered in the external AD has a Redirect URI in the format "https://{My B2C Directory Name}.b2clogin.com/{My B2C Directory Name}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp", which matches the name of my B2C instance, and I have added the client id and secret generated from that app registration and put the details into the custom identity provider I have created for the sign-in flow, as per the instructions here (including the mappings etc.):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow

I also found a slightly older tutorial here, which is pretty similar (different mappings) that I've tried to follow (and adapt the bits that are out-of-date).

https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-azure-ad-b2c-to-azure-ad-via-the-b2c-custom-identity-provider-42fbc2832e32

However when I run the user flow I get "AADSTS900971: No reply address provided." - this happens even when I run the flow directly from the User Flows tab in B2C with a 'Reply URL' explicitly set to "http://jwt.ms" (just to capture the token contents).

I'm confused about the reply URL being missing because they exist in both registered apps. Also, it's not saying they're mismatched, just that one isn't set at all (but appears to be).

It feels like I'm missing something simple - does anyone have any idea what that might be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I did a couple of things to resolve this:

Re-registered the application in the AD I want to authenticate with (following this tutorial again: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

I was careful to ensure that the redirect URI in the format:

https://{B2C Instance Name}.b2clogin.com/{B2C Instance Name}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

was all *lower* case.

I also had to change from just a 'sign-in' user flow to the 'sign-up, sign-in' one, and then applied the custom identity provider to that flow. Apparently you need that even for users from another AD to be able to complete their invite process (otherwise you just end up with a user doesn't exist error - even if you've invited/added them to the B2C users list).

I also elected to 'Grant admin consent for Default directory' under the API Permissions tab for the application being registered in the external AD (to be used for the custom identity provider).

The flow seems to work now. The only thing that would be useful would be to have an invite only sign-up, sign-in flow so that you could invite specific people without breaking the invite process.

If anyone knows how to do that please do post something.